# What is the difference between 常に、いつも、始終、しょっちゅう？

Tags: words, adverbs

What is the difference between 常に、いつも、始終、しょっちゅう？
Is it hard to know their differences? Is there any words that also have the same meaning?

Answer (score 5):

- いつも - All the time
- 常に - Continuously (this event is occurring all the time. Can also be used as a formal version of いつも)
- 始終 - all the time
- しょっちゅう - happens very often. (typically discrete events that happen often)
- いつだって - Always (but adds focus onto the fact "always" portion compared to other terms)
- ずっと - Always (and always has been and always will be)

The first three are quite similar in indicating that something is always happening and しょっちゅう indicates that something happens very frequently.

Comment: there is いつだって as well, right?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Added/

Comment: いつだって=いつであっても=いつでも=anytime  "You can ask me anytime. いつでも頼んでください"